# working ticket booking system could not validating data

Tags: php, html

For example seat no `2 5 7 8 9 25` are booked so this should be disabled and there are total 49 seats in the bus.

I'm fetching data from database but I couldn't validate it with booked ticket so disabled.

Here is code:

```
<?php  include_once("connect.php");
  $query = "SELECT `seat_no` FROM `booked` WHERE `status`='booked'";
  $exexquery = mysqli_query($con, $query); 
?> 

<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  <div class="row" style="width: 20%;margin-left: 20%"> 
  <h2>Select seats</h2>

  <?php
    $x=1;    
    while(($result_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exexquery)) || ($x < 50)) { 
      if($result_row['seat_no'] == $x ) {
  ?>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="requiring[]" value="<?php echo $i;?>" required class="required_group" disabled><?php echo $x;?></p>
  </div>

  <?php
      }
      else {
  ?>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="requiring[]" value="<?php echo $i;?>" required class="required_group"><?php echo $x;?></p>
  </div>

  <?php
      }
      $x++;
    }
  ?>

  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="feel passenger details" style="margin-left:25%"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample data structure that you are getting from `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`?

Comment: getting data in the form of assoc array

Comment: yes, I just want to have a gist on what kind of data you are getting... can you (temporarily) modify your code and insert this: `die(var_dump($result_row));` between the `while` and `if` lines? then post the output

Comment: Why couldn't you validate the status? What have you tried to debug this?

Comment: As @NicoHaase says you need to validate `status` instead

Comment: ubuntux im getting NULL as a output

Answer (score 1):

First to get all `49` records you need to remove where clause

```
$query = "SELECT `status`,`seat_no` FROM `booked`";// now you will get all 49 rows
```

Check `status` instead, Also remove condition `$x < 50` from here

```
  while($result_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exexquery)) { 
    if($result_row['status'] == 'booked') {
       // Add html to display booked seats [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 25]
    }else{
      // Add html to display available seats
    }
```

Comment: there are no 49 records there are only 10 booked ticket then how should i can do?

Answer (score 0):

From @C2486 answer you can also shorten your code to:

```php
<?php
while ($result_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exexquery)):
    $disabled = ($result_row['status'] === 'booked') ? ' disabled' : '';
?>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="requiring[]" value="<?php echo $i;?>" required class="required_group"<?php echo $disabled; ?>><?php echo $x;?></p>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```